# Adapter between tomcat and Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

What does the adapter between tomcat and Apache do?

Adapters like mod_proxy and mod_jk forwards the servelet/jsp requests from Apache to tomcat , but how does Apache handles the **response** send back from the tomcat?
[image]

Comment: Good question, but it belongs in serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the adapter between tomcat and Apache does?

It communicates between Apache HTTPD and Tomcat, often via a protocol other than HTTP.

> Adapters like jmod_jx, etc forwards the servelet/jsp requests from Apache to tomcat,

As far as I can determine via Google there is no such thing as 'jmod_jx' other than in this question.

> but how does Apache handles the response send back from the tomcat?

It forwards it to the client.

Comment: sorry it would be mod_proxy and mod_jk. Also what response does the Apache gets from tomcat in response is its static page ?

Comment: It normally doesn't send requests for static pages to Tomcat at all, so it doesn't get a response either.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong , As per my understanding adapter sits between apache and tomcat.(adding a figure to main question) When a request comes to apache for a servelet/jsp it forwards it to Tomcat. so my question was what happens when Tomcat sends the request back?

Comment: I answered that. "It forwards it to the client." Nothing else would make sense.

Comment: No, I mean tomcat forwards response directly to client or it first forwards it to Apache and then Apache sends the response to client. If the response is forwarded to Apache , is it just a static page ?

Comment: Sigh. Apache HTTPD has a connection to Tomcat over which it sends the request and receives the response, which "it forwards to the client". I have no idea why you keep banging on about static pages. The response is whatever Tomcat produces, which is whatever the JSP or Servlet or static page produces. Which it is depends on which the URL maps to. A Tomcat that could *only* produce static pages would be completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell a web server is waiting for requests.  When these requests arrive the server does whatever is needed to serve the requests by providing the necessary content.  Adding Tomcat to the mix may somewhat change this behavior.  Now the web server needs to perform the following:

- Before the first request can be served, Apache needs to load a web
  server adapter library (so Tomcat can communicate with Apache) and
  initialize it.
- When a request arrives, Apache needs to check and see if it belongs
  to a servlet; if so it needs to let the adapter take the request and
  handle it.
- Usually We'd like Apache to handle our static content, such as images
  and HTML documents, and forward all requests for dynamic content to
  Tomcat.  More specifically, we it behaves in following manner:

  - It Decides which request / type of requests should be forwarded to Tomcat
  - It forward these requests to Tomcat

Comment: Imran Thanks for your reply. But what I was trying to know was , what response does Tomcat passes back to Apache.Is it a static page?

Comment: Of course not. It is whatever the JSP or Servlet produces. What would be the point of having Tomcat if all it did was return static pages?